# Why is my Microsoft Word VBA form not showing on a MAC?

Tags: microsoft-word

Not sure if this is the right forum but here goes... I created a word document with a form and macros then saved it as a template.  The document was created with Word 2003 and saved as a template ( a .dot file).  When the user opens the .dot document, a form loads.  The user then selects some radio buttons or checkboxes on the form.  After clicking a button at the bottom of the form all controls on the form is read and used to create a word document.  The form will not appear until I set security to "low".

Now I want to tweak the old 2003 version to run on a new version of word with .docx extension (version 2011).  Also I want it to run on a Mac.  My problem is the form won't show up.  I tried going under the Word > Preference menu and selection 'Security' but I don't see options like high, medium and low.  The only option is "Worn before opening a file that contains macros".  I've tried checking and un-checking this option but my form still does not show up.  Can someone give me any idea as to how to make my form appear again?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it is because Mac Word does not always fire the various Auto macros and/or Document_New events when you open/create documents. If you are using Document_New, it has to be in ThisDocument's module.In either case, you need to introduce a delay of , say 1 second at the beginning of the AutoNew or DOcument_New routine. (Have a look for Application.OnTime, for example).